# Date not working in non ie browser

Tags: javascript

```
 function getcalculation(dt,coun){
     try
     {
         //alert("1::"+dt)
         var serdate=document.getElementById("serdate").value;
         diff  =new Date();
         var stdate=dt;
         var callcreatedate1=new Date(stdate);
         var callclosedate1=new Date(serdate);
         var t1=callcreatedate1.getTime();
         var t2=callclosedate1.getTime();
     }
```

for `callclosedate1` i get the date value as `Mon Oct 15 2012 17:45:20 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
but `callcreatedate1` is showing invalid date error, what should do for

Comment: callcreatedate1 is evaluted from the value in stdate. Thats where you issue is. stdate doesnt have a valid value for the Date() constructor

Comment: stdate value is stored from database and has the value 04/25/2012 9:00AM, how can i compare

Comment: you should not put timestamps in human readable formats into any database in case you do not have a unix timestamp right next to it.

Comment: could you edit your question and add what the value of dt is and what error you got?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is,

**in IE**

```
new Date('04/25/2012 9:00AM')
```

gives `Wed Apr 25 09:00:00 UTC+0530 2012`

but **in Chrome**

```
new Date('04/25/2012 9:00AM')
```

gives `Invalid Date`.

I dont think this is just a js issue. Considering that fact that the code works in IE, I am assuming you are using SQL Server. You have 2 options, change the format on the server side or change it on the js side. You could refer to the following [link](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/53385-SQLServer-datetime-field-doesn-t-translate-properly-as-javascript-date-object), they do provide a js solution to this problem.